# selenium.common.exceptions: session deleted because of page crash from tab crashed

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have a simple python web-scraper I'm running on ubuntu (EC2 instance, t2.small), which so far just prints out a list of urls:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import string
import json
import geocoder
import mapbox
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt
import re
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementNotVisibleException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.add_argument('--window-size=1420,1080')
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
chrome_options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
chrome_options.add_argument("--remote-debugging-port=9222")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
chrome_options.binary_location='/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
chrome_driver_binary = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=chrome_options)

#Set base url (SAN FRANCISCO)
base_url = 'https://www.bandsintown.com/?place_id=ChIJIQBpAG2ahYAR_6128GcTUEo&page='#san francisco



events = []
eventContainerBucket = []

for i in range(1,3):
    print(i)
    #cycle through pages in range
    driver.get(base_url + str(i))
    pageURL = base_url + str(i)
    print(pageURL)
    # get events links
    event_list = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div[class^=_3buUBPWBhUz9KBQqgXm-gf] a[class^=_3UX9sLQPbNUbfbaigy35li]')
    # collect href attribute of events in even_list
    events.extend(list(event.get_attribute("href") for event in event_list))

print ("total events: ", (len(events)))

#GET request user-agent
headers = {'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36"}


# iterate through all events and open them.
item = {}
allEvents = []
for event in events:

    driver.get(event)
    currentUrl = driver.current_url
    print(currentUrl)
    try:
        currentRequest = requests.get(currentUrl, headers=headers)
        print (currentRequest)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(e)
        continue

        print("continuing!")
```

However, the script runs through about 3 urls successfully and then crashes with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "BandsintownWebScraper.py", line 117, in <module>
    driver.get(event)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 333, in get
    self.execute(Command.GET, {'url': url})
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from tab crashed
  (Session info: headless chrome=91.0.4472.114)
```

`df -h` in the terminal reveals:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            979M     0  979M   0% /dev
tmpfs           199M  768K  198M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.7G  7.7G   60M 100% /
tmpfs           993M     0  993M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           993M     0  993M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/11316
/dev/loop1       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2066
/dev/loop2       56M   56M     0 100% /snap/core18/2074
/dev/loop3      100M  100M     0 100% /snap/core/11187
/dev/loop4       29M   29M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/2012
/dev/loop5       34M   34M     0 100% /snap/amazon-ssm-agent/3552
tmpfs           199M     0  199M   0% /run/user/1000
```

From what I've read, this might be due to low available memory?  How can I fix this?  Specifically, is there a way I need to partition more memory on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.answertopia.com/ubuntu/adding-and-managing-ubuntu-swap-space/

Add some swap space. If it works, then it was memory related; if not, then it is likely python related - although I see nothing wrong with your code at first glance and it runs fine (to completion) on my computer (16gb of RAM).